# C# method declarations using the lambda operator

Tags: c#, lambda

While researching [C# operator overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx), I stumbled across this block of code on the MSDN web site:

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) =>
    new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);

// Override ToString() to display a complex number 
// in the traditional format:
public override string ToString() => $"{this.real} + {this.imaginary}";
```

This is a really useful way of defining simple methods in certain circumstances, but I don't recall ever seeing it described anywhere. I tried searching the C# 5.0 language specification for a description of this method declaration syntax, but could find nothing. I also found nothing in my web searches.

Two questions:

1. In which version of C# did this method declaration syntax become available?
2. Where in the language specification is this syntax described?

Comment: This is a C# 6 feature.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot.  I'm surprised I wasn't able to find anything on the web about it.  I guess my search-engine-fu needs improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was added in C# 6, you can read about it on the official Github of the new compiler [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-method-like-members).